# Issues with checkbox's indeterminate state with internet explorer 8

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Hi when trying to set the state of a check box to indeterminate I get a weird appearance of the state on IE, a white checked sign, in stead of the usual sign 'check box filled with blue'. I this a known issue , is there any way to work around this ?

Tried this

var checkbox = document.getElementById("mycheckbox");
checkbox.indeterminate = true;

And this

```
$("#mycheckbox")[0].indeterminate = true;
```

And this

```
$("#mycheckbox").prop("indeterminate", true);
```

With IE I'm getting this : [image]

With FF I'm getting this : [image]

Thanks.

Comment: Like the checkboxes themselves, the indeterminate state of a checkbox looks different in different browsers. While the IE style is the one known from Windows forms applications, the FF style looks odd (unreasonable) to me.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly Understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a bit more, i have found a way to replicate FF's look on IE. It's possible using images as shown in here => http://shamsmi.blogspot.fr/2008/12/tri-state-checkbox-using-javascript.html

Comment: Good find. It is sad that HTML only provides 2 states (checked and unchecked) for checkboxes. Whereas a bit field in a database can have 3 states (true, false and NULL).